# Surpress PhpStorm Inspection for specific types

Tags: php, phpstorm, inspector, inspection

I've configured PhpStorm code Inspection in my project recently, and I noticed some undesired behavior.

The PhpStorm code Inspector seems to always have wrong mentions about code that is inside an `eval()`. For example, undefined constant, undefined variable, etc. when everything is actually fine.

With this reason I would like to disable the PhpStorm Inspector to look at every `eval()` that occurs in my entire project.

Now I know I could do this by adding `/** NoInspection ... */` in or above each line containing `eval()`, but I figured there might be another (easier) way to solve this issue, since there is **a lot** of `eval()` in my code.

Does someone have advice for me?

Comment: Please provide some standalone example (use brand new empty project for this; makes it easier to make such code sample) so that we can copy-paste it and see what can be done. I never use `eval()` myself so do not know what sort of code you have got there to trigger such behaviour and what inspection got triggered.

Comment: I may only say that this could be related to the new functionality (2020.1 AFAIK) when PHP become injectable into `eval()` and other similar places like Markdown doc fragments etc (before it was treated as a plain string).

Comment: @LazyOne I don't think you understand, this has nothing to do with a specific scenario, it's just a general question regarding disabling PhpStorm Inspection for specific parts of code. Could be to NOT inspect anything after echo, could be to NOT inspect anything specified in eval, could be to NOT inspect inside a method that returns a string...

Comment: There is no suppression/"do not inspect" for "parts of code". 1) It's either a suppression of specific inspection (that can be for 1 statement below or for the whole file) or 2) disabling all inspections in a whole file. Specific inspection can either be suppressed via comment in that file ... or disabled for a custom scope (which is file/folder based).

Comment: Would you like to just disable PHP in `eval()` and treat it as a plain text? This may solve your issue especially if you do not write such code and just work with already written one (no injections = no language specific inspections). `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections` -- locate **PHP in eval** entry and disable it.